# PDF4Net: Text Justification on Last Line on Paragraph

Tags: c#, pdf

I am using a dll called PDF4NET from O2 Solutions.

I have code that looks like this:

```
PDFTextFormatOptions tfo new PDFTextFormatOptions;
tfo.Align = TextAlign.TopJustified;

tfo.KeepWhiteSpaces = True;
tfo.LineSpacing = 2;
string ltrtxt = "IMPORTANT: This is just some text representing a paragraph. This is just some extra text to make the paragraph longer.";
pdfPage.Canvas.DrawHTMLTextBox(ltrtxt, 
    PDFReportsConfig.Arial_HTML11, 
    Nothing, 
    PDFReportsConfig.BlackBrush, 
    y, x, 3, 2, tfo);
```

That creates a paragraph that looks like this:

```
IMPORTANT: This is just some  text 
representing a paragraph.  This is 
just some  extra text  to make the 
paragraph                  longer.
```

That is, the paragraph is both right and left justified.

I want to maintain the justification, but I also want the last line to not be justified.

```
IMPORTANT: This is just some  text 
representing a paragraph.  This is 
just some  extra text  to make the 
paragraph longer.
```

How do I get the paragraph to be fully justified, but allow the last line to be left justified?

When I google `"PDFTextFormatOptions"` (with quotes) i get to two results.

I inherited this project so I don't know where the original documentation is.

[EDIT]
I attempted to add newlines to the end of the strings, but it did not help.  I added them like this:

```
ltrtxt += vbCrLf
ltrtxt += vbCr
ltrtxt += vbLf
```

That is: I tried all three individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `"<br/>"` html element at the end of your text, the last line will no longer be justified.

Note that older version of PDF4NET may require `"<br/>"` rather than `"<br>"`.